# Django CreateView Multiple Object Insert

Tags: python, django, django-views

I no have an idea what title should be,
but here I have a case that if a form was submitted it will find data from other model and insert every matched.

currently here my code.

here my `models.py`

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    value = models.DecimalField()

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateField()
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='foo')
```

here my `views.py`

```
class Foo(CreateView):
    fields = ('name', 'value')
    model = models.Foo

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        for i in range(30):
            self.object.bar.foo.append(self.object.id)


        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

`Bar` have `ForeignKey` to `Foo` example if form was submitted with `range(30)` it will find `Bar` and insert (`append`) Foo `id` for every data. now i do with this,

`self.object.bar.foo.append(self.object.id)` but error said `'Foo' object has no attribute 'bar'`

how to insert `append` multiple data to `Bar` from `Foo(CreateView)` ?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,  `append` is method of `list`, and FK relation is definitely not a list. Secondly,  you have used `related_name='foo'` in your `Bar` model,  so actually you can get `Bar` from `Foo` by using `foo.foo`. I am sure this is an error. As long as one `Foo` can have many `Bar`,  your `related_name` should be `bars`,  so you would be able to use `foo.bars.all()`.
To create `Bar`,  you should firstly save your `Foo`,  so use `commit=True`.
And the last. In your for loop use `Bar.objects.create(foo=self.object)`. 
Your also would like to use `bulk_create` to optimize that loop,  so you don't make 30 queries to databases but just one. To implement it,  create a list `bars = []` before loop. Than inside loop use `bars.append(Bar(foo=self.object)`. Here `append` is method of `list`,  so your are just creating a list of `Bar` objects without saving them to database. And finally after loop use `Bar.objects.bulk_create(bars)` to actually save them to database.

I have reread your question and maybe I have missed the point. How do you want to 'find'  your `Bar`? Also,  you can't add multiple `Foo` to your `Bar`,  because it if FK which means single object.

Comment: thank you, so on your answer ` Also, you can't add multiple Foo to your Bar, because it if FK which means single object.` so theres no way to update `foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='foo')` ?... in case i have 30 Bar object and need to update it.

Comment: It is not really clear what are you trying to achieve. Where is your 30 Bar objects? How do you get them from posted form?  If they are all referencing the same Foo,  you just need to update it with new data if I understand you correctly. Then you don't need Bar here at all,  just update the Foo object